# Http response error when sending a post request Angular 4

Tags: angular, http-error

I get this error when receiving a response from the server even though I put `responseType` as `'text'` in the header :

```
   HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://beta.rokhas.ma/karazortal/web.jsp", ok: false, …}
error
:
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 15 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "↵↵ ↵ ↵ ↵↵ ↵   ↵↵<!doctype html>↵ ↵↵<html lang="fr">…ight:0;border:0"></iframe>↵</body> ↵    ↵</html>↵"}
headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message:"Http failure during parsing for https://beta.rokhas.ma/karazortal/web.jsp"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok:false
status:200
statusText: "OK"
url : "https://beta.rokhas.ma/karazortal/web.jsp"
__proto__ : HttpResponseBase
```

I want to display this HTML body content in my app.

**myservice.ts**

```
logIn(user){
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('j_username', user.email);
    body.set('j_password', user.password);
    let headers= new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    headers.append('responseType', 'text');
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers  
    };   
    console.log(body.toString());  
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL+'karazortal/kas/signin',  
     body.toString(),  httpOptions)

  }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data. BTW, even if you had to modify headers to set the response type, your code doesn't, because HttpHeaders is immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is work for me. please check it out.

```
logIn(user) {
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('j_username', user.email);
  body.set('j_password', user.password);
  let headers= new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: headers
  };
  console.log(body.toString());
  return this.http.post(this.API_URL+'karazortal/kas/signin', body.toString(),{responseType: 'text'},  httpOptions)
}
```